# Can I add a height measurement in a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I just need to know if it is possible to add a height measurement in on the command block in Minecraft light you can do radius. Would it maybe be something like h=`<Hight>`

Comment: What do you mean height measurment? Do you mean y check?

Comment: Like a measurement upwards? like you can do a radius of 5 blocks, can you do it measuring upwards?

Comment: So, check if someone is above a certain y level?

Comment: Yes! So its like /tp @a[name=n, r=5,] X Y Z. Could I do /tp @a[name=n, r=5, y=h] X Y Z????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifiying an area

```
/tp @a[name=n, x = <x1>, y = <y1>, z = <z1>, dx = <x length>, dy = <y length>, dz = <z length>] X Y Z
```